# Usage of JLog in a component controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

In my component controller, i have implemented JLog but this issue that i have is that the file log isn't created in directoy /logs.

There is the code of the controller that i'am using :

```
class TdsmanagerControllerWebservice extends JControllerLegacy {
    public function update() {
       jimport('joomla.log.log');


        JLog::addLogger(
            array(
                'text_file' => 'com_tdsmanager.webservice.' . date('Y-m-d') . 'log.php'
            ),
            JLog::ALL,
            array('com_tdsmanager')
        );

        JLog::add(
           "We are in update step", JLog::INFO, 'com_tdsmanager.webservice'
        );
    }
}
```

Do-you have an idea why JLog not working here ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Could you try changing `array('com_tdsmanager')` to just `'com_tdsmanager'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the third parameter of `JLog::add()` is wrong. This parameter is a category and you have set it to `'com_tdsmanager'` in `JLog::addLogger()`. So you should use the same in `JLog::add()`:

```
JLog::add("We are in update step", JLog::INFO, 'com_tdsmanager');
```

See the doc https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog